# Securing a Password in a Background Job in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I have a access token that is stored encrypted as an ENV variable on a server. When someone wants to generate a report - they send up a password which is used to decrypt the encrypted access token (currently using `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor`) then the access token is used to make some API calls to a third party needed to generate the report.

The issue I'm running into is the network API call to the third party is slow (a few minutes) and causing web requests to timeout. The project has Sidekiq + ActiveJob integrated and I thought it'd be great to queue a job (then the slow runtime won't matter).

I'm unclear now how to properly handle the password. I can't use the password as an argument for the job (since it then gets stored in Redis). Likewise I can't put the decrypted access token (for the same reason). Do I have any options? If the third party let me convert the encrypted access key into a limited use / expiring key via a quick API I could do that prior to enqueueing - but I don't beleive that is an option. Any other options?

Comment: Could they supply the password where it's been encrypted using a public key so only your local private key can decode it?

Comment: @tadman not sure how this helps. Where could the private key be stored? Would it be possible to prevent someone with access to the job data (enqueued with whatever params needed for the public / private keys) from later making unauthorized API calls given that they had the encrypted access token?

Comment: Unless you run it on a separate machine, background jobs will probably have access to the same runtime environment as the caller (at least for Sidekiq or Resque). So it's not necessary to pass it as a parameter or otherwise store it in Redis. You could retrieve it from an environment variable, for example, or a file.

Comment: You'd have to keep the worker machine with access to that private key locked down tight, but no matter what you do you'll have to secure *something* that way. I thought you wanted to get the password off of potentially shared resources like Redis.

Comment: @maxple running on Heroku with separate worker dynos (servers) from API dynos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq Enterprise supports encrypted job data, designed to solve exactly the problem you have.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Encryption

Comment: Thanks so much for authoring Sidekiq. Appreciate your response!